# Python- Trying to print a variable and using (str) in front of number, but still getting a syntax error

Tags: string, python-3.x, variables

I created a variable called "age = 23". I try and add it to another variable called "message" and specify it as a string using the (str) tag in front of the "age" variable.

```
age = 23
message = "Happy " + (str)age + "rd 
birthday!"

print(message)
```

But whenever I try and run the code it comes back with a snytax error that looks like this:

```
line 7
message = "Happy " + (str)age + "rd 
birthday!"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
1|potter:/ $
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code or data as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor so it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask] good questions, that includes creating a [mcve].

Comment: To get the `str` of an `int` you call the `str()` function, e.g. `str(age)` - you are not casting it to `str` like `C` code. You may want to take some basic python tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the brackets in the wrong place, I'm not going to use your example as you've added it as an image, as AChampion mentioned, but an example is:

```
number = 34
message = "The number is " + str(number)
print(message)
```

I'd recommend taking some time to read the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/), as this can help get your head around the language and its more basic uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
message = "Happy " + str(age) + "rd birthday!"
print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning Python from other languages such as C, you might know this method:

```
age = 23
print ('Happy %srd birthday!' % (age))
print ('Happy {}rd birthday!'.format(age)) # Use this
```

Might help: https://pyformat.info/